# Can't start blender on Ubuntu 17.04 zetsy

Tags: 17.04, blender

When I tried to run Blender3D nothing happens. 
On terminal the output is:

```
blender: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libavcodec-extra57 already installed on my system.
I tried to uninstall, install libavcodec, blender3d. Nothing changed.

PS:I am using this system since 15.04, I may have messed up libav or system settings compiling/using/programing opencv.

Comment: It seems the problem originates from the fact that you are not getting blender from the zesty repo. zesty blender is linked to / deps on `libavcodec(-extra)57`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/blender , while xenial blender is linked to / deps on `libavcodec-ffmpeg(-extra)56`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/blender ; not sure why it is happening to you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. All I did was:

```
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/blender.conf
```

and add below to the this file

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

after I run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Then blender starts normally.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Blender was built and linked against the library named `libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56` which isn't there. The 56 at the end is the version which is one older than what you now have installed.

You can try creating a [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ln.1posix.html) with that name that points to the v57 version you have installed. `ln -s /usr/local/lib/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.57 /usr/local/lib/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56`. If you don't have the exact filename `libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.57` try something similar, maybe `libavcodec-extra.so.57` For small version changes that may work, larger variations are more likely to fail.

Find a third party repository that has blender built against libavcodec v57. Or one that has libavcodec v56.

If you can find a copy of `libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56` and don't want to replace over your existing libavcodec version, you should be able to create a lib dir next to the blender binary and place it in there, this will be easier if you have a [self contained copy of blender](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.78/) rather than a system installed copy.

If you do have `libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56` installed then it may be a case of not being able to find it, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your environment can fix that.

[Build blender](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake) yourself, which will always be linked with libraries you have installed.